# c++ check Child status

Tags: c++, fork

I have a code like this:

```
fork();
if child:
   execvp("sth");   //Just returns if errors
if parent:
   save child pid;
```

In anther function I want to check if child finished or not, and i don't want to use `waitpid`. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: why you dont want to use `waitpid()`?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid `waitpid` isnt blocking if you use `options = WNOHANG` (return immediately if no child has exited.)

Comment: I used `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` at last and solve my problem some how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a signal handler to handle SIGCHLD, which will be delivered to the parent when the child ends.  Technically that's "another function" even if it is called asynchronously.  You should still use `waitpid` even after getting the signal though and if you have multiple children it is the only way I know that you will be able to tell them apart.

Comment: I used `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` at last and solve my problem some how.